# Converting Qbytearray to image blackberry 10 cascades

Tags: blackberry-10

How can I convert Qbytearray to image, so that I can show in imageView. Any sample codes will be useful

Answer (score 1):

QImage has a constructor that takes a `uchar* data`. I suppose the buffer is stored in QByteArray, so try to use the data in the byte array to construct a QImage using the appropriate constructor. If your QImage is valid, it is quite easy from now on:

```
QImage swapped = originalImageFromBuffer.rgbSwapped();

PixelBufferData pbd(RGBX /* or RGBA_PRE, depends on the buffer format*/, swapped.width(), swapped.height(), swapped.width(), (void*)swapped.constBits());

myImageFrame->setImage(pbd);
```